# Right commercial oven for Frozen Foods?

Tags: oven, frozen

I'd like to provide an array of meals that are frozen and can be quickly heated and served. I have reviewed different models and there are 3 kinds I think:

1) Steam Combi - e.g. Rational selfcookingcentre

2) Convection+Impingement- e.g. MerryChef E2S
 ﻿
3) Convection + Microvave e.g. Menumaster

The menu would consist of the following types of food:
Lasagna
Pasta
Rice
Noodles
Curries

Objective is To be able to put frozen food directly into the oven (without thawing) and using a particular setting for each item type, the oven should be able to bring it 'closest' to freshly cooked food w.r.t. texture especially.. in under 10min.

Thanks,
Nipun

Answer (score 1):

The Rational oven is definitely more flexible - it usually offers a dry and a wet oven capacity. If you're reheating any wet ingredients like pasta, rice, sauces, you'll find the merry chef very unsuitable.

Options 2 and 3 that you've listed are good for far reheating of relatively small numbers of portions that need heat + crisp eg pies, roast potatoes. But they're not so good for wet foods or large batches